# In Java, is a char[] an object?

Tags: java, arrays, object, primitive-types

I'm new to Java but if I understand correctly, a char is a primitive.

Doing char temp and temp.hashCode() won't compile but doing a char[] temp2 = new char[2] and temp2.hashCode() will compile and execute.

Does this mean somehow a char[] is an object???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

a `char` is a primitive, but an array of type `char` is an object

one way to tell is by dynamically instantiating it:

```
final Object charArray = Array.newInstance(Character.TYPE, 5);
System.out.println(charArray.getClass().getComponentType());
```

Output:

> char

([`Character.TYPE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#TYPE) is a reference to the primitive class `char`. Another way to access that class is through `char.class`)

Comment: *It's the only way you can access that class.* Wrong, you can use `char.class`.

Comment: @Willi true, forgot about that. Edited my answer

Comment: Another interesting point, `char.class` is just a reference to `Character.class` (according to http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Character.java.html). So i guess we were both right ;)

Comment: a reference to Character.TYPE, that is.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. All arrays are objects, even arrays of primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all arrays are Objects in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every Array of every type is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes arrays are objects in java.

Answer (score 0):

An array isn't just several primitive types, it also has a "length" field.  Primitive types don't have fields.  Another thing that sets arrays appart from primitive types is they are references and thus have to be garbage collected.