# How to convert an int[] array to a List?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I expected this code to display `true`:

```
int[] array = {1, 2};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(1));
```

Comment: Thats the way to convert an array to List. Just remember that the list is immutable. Try outputting the content of the list, and you will see that it contains the 1 and 2 value

Comment: @Shervin: try it yourself and you'll see that it doesn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Arrays.asList(array)` will result in a singleton list of an `int[]`.

It works as you expect if you change `int[]` to `Integer[]`. Don't know if that helps you though.

Answer (score 37):

The method [`Arrays.asList(T ...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) is, when generics are erased and varargs are transformed, actually equal to a method of type `Arrays.ofList(Object[])` (which is the, binary equivalent, JDK 1.4 version of the same Method).

An array of primitives is an `Object` (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146928/in-java-is-a-char-an-object/4146957#4146957)), but not an `Object[]`, so the compiler thinks you are using the varargs version and generates an Object array around your int array. You could illustrate what's happening by adding an extra step:

```
int[] array = {1, 2};
List<int[]> listOfArrays = Arrays.asList(array);
System.out.println(listOfArrays.contains(1));
```

This compiles and is equivalent to your code. It also obviously returns false.

The compiler translates varargs calls into calls with a single array, so calling a varargs  method that expects parameters `T ...` with parameters `T t1, T t2, T t3` is equivalent to calling it with `new T[]{t1, t2, t3}` but the special case here is that varargs with primitives will be autoboxed before the array is created if the method needs an object array. So the compiler thinks the int array is passed in as a single Object and creates a single element array of type `Object[]`, which it passes to `asList()`.

So here's the above code once again, the way the compiler implements it internally:

```
int[] array = {1, 2};
// no generics because of type erasure
List listOfArrays = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{array});
System.out.println(listOfArrays.contains(1));
```

Here are some good and bad ways to call `Arrays.asList()` with int values:

```
// These versions use autoboxing (which is potentially evil),
// but they are simple and readable

// ints are boxed to Integers, then wrapped in an Object[]
List<Integer> good1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
// here we create an Integer[] array, and fill it with boxed ints
List<Integer> good2 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3});

// These versions don't use autoboxing,
// but they are very verbose and not at all readable:

// this is awful, don't use Integer constructors
List<Integer> ugly1 = Arrays.asList(
    new Integer(1),new Integer(2),new Integer(3)
);
// this is slightly better (it uses the cached pool of Integers),
// but it's still much too verbose
List<Integer> ugly2 = Arrays.asList(
    Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(3)
);

// And these versions produce compile errors:
// compile error, type is List<int[]>
List<Integer> bad1 = Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3});
// compile error, type is List<Object>
List<Integer> bad2 = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{1,2,3});
```

**Reference:**

- [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) > [Classes and Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) > [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)  > [Varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs)
- [`Arrays.asList(T ...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

---

But to actually solve your problem in a simple way:

There are some library solutions in Apache Commons / Lang (see [Bozho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324633/how-to-convert-an-int-array-to-a-list/4324652#4324652)) and in [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

- [`Ints.contains(int[], int)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#contains%28int%5B%5D%2C%20int%29) checks whether an array of ints contains a given int
- [`Ints.asList(int ...)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29) creates a List of Integers from an int array

Comment: `Integer[]` is an object too though.

Comment: I know, but it's also an `Object[]`, which is a better match

Comment: ouch, that pricks with a sweet pain

Comment: int[] cannot be cast to Object[] (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154769/why-can-you-cast-int-to-object-but-not-to-object)) but is cast to Object instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObjectArray(array))
```

(`ArrayUtils` is from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/))

But if you want to just call `contains` there is no need of that. Simply use `Arrays.binarySearch(..)` (sort the array first)

Comment: May be we can add that ArrayUtils is a part of apache commons: http://commons.apache.org/

Comment: Excuse me, i'm time-travel-blind.

Comment: Now it is: Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array));

Answer (score 2):

> How to convert an int[] array to a List?

Direct answer using modern Java features:

```
int[] array = {1, 2};
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(array).boxed().toList();
System.out.println(list.contains(1)); // true
```

Note: `toList()` is available since Java 16.

An alternative since Java 8 would be `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: but be aware that the list returned by `Stream.toList()` is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(array));
```

returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your understanding of `Arrays.asList(T... a)` is wrong. You wouldn't be the first person to make an assumption as to how it works.

Try it with

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1, 2).contains(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Autoboxing just doesn't work the way you want it to in this case. The following code may be a bit verbose, but does the job of converting an int array to a list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
for (int value : array) {
    list.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code displays true:

```
Integer[] array = {1, 2};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(1));
```

(Your version fails, since Int's not beeing objects, but Int[] is an object. Therefor you will call asList(T... a) with one element beeing a Collection, since it is not possible to have an Collection a.)

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
Arrays.asList(array)
```

on your array of primitives, you get a List instance containing one object: an array of int values!  You have to first convert the array of primitives into an array of objects, as @Bozho suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check whether the array contains certain element just iterate over array and search for element. This will take o(n/2). All other solutions are less effective. Any method that copies array to list must iterate over array and therefore this operation only requires n atomic assignments.

Comment: *Any method that copies array to list must iterate over array* That's not true. `Arrays.asList()` uses the supplied array to back the list, so it will only iterate when searching, just as what you are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a third-party library, the following options are possible using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections). Both primitive `IntList` and boxed `List<Integer>` can be used to solve the problem depending on what you require. The lists can also either be mutable or immutable, again based on your requirements.

```
@Test
public void intArrayToList()
{
    int[] array = {1, 2};

    // Creates an Eclipse Collections MutableIntList from the int[]
    MutableIntList mutableIntList = IntLists.mutable.with(array);

    // Creates an Eclipse Collections ImmutableIntList from the int[]
    ImmutableIntList immutableIntList = IntLists.immutable.with(array);

    IntList expectedIntList = IntLists.immutable.with(1, 2);
    Assertions.assertTrue(mutableIntList.contains(1));
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedIntList, mutableIntList);
    Assertions.assertTrue(immutableIntList.contains(1));
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedIntList, immutableIntList);

    // Converts the MutableIntList to a MutableList<Integer>
    // Boxes the int values as Integer objects
    MutableList<Integer> mutableList = mutableIntList.collect(i -> i);

    // Converts the ImmutableIntList to an ImmutableList<Integer>
    // Boxes the int values as Integer objects
    ImmutableList<Integer> immutableList = immutableIntList.collect(i -> i);

    List<Integer> expectedList = List.of(1, 2);
    Assertions.assertTrue(mutableList.contains(1));
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedList, mutableList);
    Assertions.assertTrue(immutableList.contains(1));
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedList, immutableList);
}
```

`MutableIntList` and `ImmutableIntList` will hold onto a primitive `int[]` so there will be no boxing of `int` values to `Integer`. `MutableList<Integer>` and `ImmutableList<Integer>` will hold onto boxed `Integer` values.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is a method call you could use. Try it like this

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
  {
    list.add(array[index]);
  }
```

Comment: That's very old-school code. See dogbane's answer for the more modern version of this