# "Generic" solution for primitive array?

Tags: java, arrays, refactoring, primitive-types

I have classes that for processing primitive array input: CharArrayExtractor for char[], ByteArrayExtractor for byte[], IntegerArrayExtractor for int[], ...

```
public void CharArrayExtractor {

    public List<Record> extract(char[] source) {
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
        int recordStartFlagPos = -1;
        int recordEndFlagPos = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            if (source[i] == RECORD_START_FLAG) {
                recordStartFlagPos = i;
            } else if (source[i] == RECORD_END_FLAG) {
                recordEndFlagPos = i;
            }
            if (recordStartFlagPos != -1 && recordEndFlagPos != -1) {
                Record newRecord = makeRecord(source, recordStartFlagPos,
                        recordEndFlagPos);
                records.add(newRecord);
                recordStartFlagPos = -1;
                recordEngFlagPos = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void ByteArrayExtractor {

    public List<Record> extract(byte[] source) {
        // filter and extract data from the array.
    }
}

public void IntegerArrayExtractor {

    public List<Record> extract(int[] source) {
        // filter and extract data from the array.
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the algorithm for extracting the data is the same, only the types of input are different.  Everytime the algorithm changes, I have to change all of the extractor classes.

Is there a way to make extractor classes more "generics"?

Best regards.

**EDIT**: It seems that every suggestion so far is to use autoboxing to archive generic. But the number of elements of the array is often large, so I avoid using autoboxing.

I added more specific implementation of how the data is being extracted. Hope it will clarify something.

Comment: For primitives? No, if you look at any class in the Java API you will see that the creators of the language also use the same solution you use above, where the method is overriden for each primitive type. Have a look at the `println()` method here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: How can the algoritm be the same, when your datatype is different?

Comment: @Martijn I don't know it would be easier with templates.

Comment: Similar, but not an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324633/how-to-convert-an-int-array-to-a-list

Comment: there is no boxing in my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Idea**

Or a different approach is wrapping the primitive arrays and covering them with the methods you use for your algorithm.

```
public PrimitiveArrayWrapper {
    private byte[] byteArray = null;
    private int[] intArray = null;
    ...

    public PrimitiveArrayWrapper(byte[] byteArray) {
        this.byteArray = byteArray;
    }

    // other constructors

    public String extractFoo1(String pattern) {
        if(byteArray != null) {
          // do action on byteArray
        } else if(....) 
        ...
    }
}

public class AlgorithmExtractor {
    public List<Record> do(PrimitiveArrayWrapper wrapper) {
        String  s= wrapper.extractFoo1("abcd");
        ...
    }
}
```

This mainly depends if you have a lot of methods to call which you would have to cover. but at least you must not edit the algorithm more over the way how to access the primitive array. Furthermor you would also be able to use a different object inside the wrapper.

**Old Idea**

Either use generics or what i also think about is to have three methods which convert the primitive types into value types.

```
public void Extractor {
    public List<Record> extract(byte[] data) {
        InternalExtractor<Byte> ie = new InternalExtractor<Byte>();
        return ie.internalExtract(ArrayUtils.toObject(data));
    }

    public List<Record> extract(int[] data) {
        ...
    }
}

public void InternalExtractor<T> {
    private List<Record> internalExtract(T[] data) {
        // do the extraction
    }
}
```

ArrayUtils is a helper class from commons lang from Apache.

Comment: You maybe don't want to use autoboxing with an array of 8162 bytes.

Comment: Ok if you have that sizes this is not optional. Let me write a differnt idea down.

Comment: Just saw at your updated example above. This would be an affordable effort to write such a wrapper as proposed above. Because as I see you don't have that much calls to the array itself.

Comment: I just came up a similar idea with yours too. I think this is the best way we can do with my question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how your filter will work as it will not know anything about the type the array contains.

Using reflection you can possibly do what you want but you will loose compile time type safety.

The java.lang.reflect.Array class provides functions for manipulating an array without knowing its type.

The [Array.get()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29) function  will return the value at the requested index of the array and if it is a primitive wrap it in its corresponding Object type.  The downside is you have to change your method signature to accept Object instead of specific array types which means the compiler can no longer check the input parameters for you.

Your code would become:

```
public class ArrayExtractor {

    public List<Record> extract(Object array) {
        // filter and extract data from the array.
        int length = Array.getLength(array);
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            Object value = Array.get(array, index);

            // somehow filter using value here
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I would prefer having type safety over using reflection even if it is a little more verbose.

Comment: This is ugly as hell but +1 for providing something that would actually work :-)

Comment: this introduces boxing, which OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface Source
    int length();
    int get(int index);

extract(final byte[] source)
    extract( new Source(){
        int length(){ return source.length; }
        int get(int i){ return source[i]; }
    } );

// common algorithm
extract(Source source)
    for(int i=0; i<source.lenth(); i++)
        int data = source.get(i);
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to achieve. But maybe you can work with primitive wrappers instead? Then you could write generic `Extractor<? extends Number>` (here `Number` is the abstract class extended by all primitive wrappers).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing each type, pass the class of the type as the below:

```
    public List<Record> extract(Class srcClass) {
        if (int[].class.equals(srcClass) {

           // filter and extract data from the int[] array.
        }
        else if (..) // do same for other types
    }
```

Comment: Then I still have to write implementation for each type of primitives. And when the algorithm changes, it's still the same.

Comment: @genzer, not at all. the if part just encapsulates the part where u need the type information, the rest of the algo is outside the if-else blocks. you have to design it that way. we have been through this multiple times.

Comment: can u give me more explanation please?

Comment: @genzer, "irreputable" has given the asnwer i was asking you to keep out of if else block

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Extractor<T> {

    public List<Record> extract(T[] source) {
        // filter and extract data from the array.
    }
}
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: Since he is trying to use primitives, he will have to define `extract` to take in just `T`, and his concrete definition of the generic would be `int[]`, `char[]`...  Otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: This will not work for primitive arrays, sorry. The erasure of T is Object, and primitives are not Objects. There is no auto-boxing for primitive arrays.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd so primitives !extend object? Learn something new every time I'm on here

Comment: @kmb385 primitives do not extend object, but primitive[]s do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
public class ArrayExtractor<T>
{
    public List<T> extract (T[] source)
    {
        // filter and extract data from the array.
    }
}
```

You would have a generic Extractor class and your implementation would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think is is possible to do create a method like this:

```
public List<Record> extract(List<Number> source) {
    // filter and extract data from the array.
}
```

And use `Arrays.asList(yourPrimaryArrayType)`, to make it compatible.

---

After my tests and the comment of *Sean Patrick Floyd*, you will  be able to do this by create once some helper methods, for converting primitive arrays to lists:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] i = {1,2,3};
    System.out.println(extract(asPrimitiveList(i)));
}

public static List<Object> extract(List<Number> source) {
    List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
    l.add(0);
    for (Number n : source)
    {
        // I know this line is rubbish :D
        l.set(0, ((Number) l.get(0)).doubleValue() + n.doubleValue());
    }
    return l;
}

private static List<Number> asPrimitiveList(int[] ia)
{
    List<Number> l = new ArrayList<Number>(ia.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; ++i)
    {
        l.add(ia[i]);
    }
    return l;
}

private static List<Number> asPrimitiveList(byte[] ia)
{
    List<Number> l = new ArrayList<Number>(ia.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; ++i)
    {
        l.add(ia[i]);
    }
    return l;
}

private static List<Number> asPrimitiveList(char[] ia)
{
    List<Number> l = new ArrayList<Number>(ia.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; ++i)
    {
        l.add(ia[i]);
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Another nice try which won't work either. see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324633/how-to-convert-an-int-array-to-a-list/4324662#4324662

Comment: @Matrijn these helper methods already exist in commons/lang (2 steps: `Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(ints[]))` and in Guava (1 step: `Ints.asList(int[])`)

Answer (score 0):

You cant use Javas generics because of primitive type source, your best bet is to try some java reflection api to analyze the incoming source and invoke the extractors on your own.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is never possible.

For example take a look at documentation of [ArrayUtils.copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29). And there exists other methods for remaining primitives. This is kind of same behavior (literally) you wanted. If it was possible similar code should exists somewhere else.

Additionally we can discuss more about how generic works, but it would be another issue, i guess.

Comment: I did have a look at Arrays source code. The `copyOf` series methods take advantage of System.arraycopy, which is native. It seems that Java can't do anything about this kind of problem.

Comment: Also you can drill down to `Arrays#sort()` method

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should be able to use generics:

```
    interface Extractor<T, R> {
        public List<R> extract(T source);
    }

    class BaseExtractor<T> implements Extractor<T, Record>
    {
        public List<Record> extract(T source)
        {
            //do your thing
        }
    }
```

Here, you would have to assume that `T` is a primitive array, as you cannot use primitives in generic definitions.

Or else, you could use the wrapper Objects and do it this way:

```
    interface Extractor<T, R> {
        public List<R> extract(T[] source);
    }

    class BaseExtractor<T> implements Extractor<T, Record>
    {
        public List<Record> extract(T[] source)
        {
            //do your thing
        }
    }
```

In this case, your generic `T` can be `Byte`, `Integer`, etc.

Comment: That's about as verbose as the original version.

Comment: Since the size of the input array is often large, so autoboxing is what I want to avoid here.

Comment: As with your first suggestion, how can I access the value of the array if I use `extract(T source)`?

Comment: Excellent point, I am not sure you can do it the first way AND access the individual elements while still being generic.  You may have to go with the other suggestion to just create each method...