# what's the quickest way to convert an array to a LIST or Set?

Tags: java

In Java, what's the qucikest way to convert an array to a List or a set?

```
String[] a = {"Test1", "test2"};

List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: *"what's the qucikest way"*  Ask random strangers to do it for you?  Oh wait, you already have that covered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `java.util.Arrays` class.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b"});
```

Note that the implementation of `List` you get by the above method isn't the same as `java.util.ArrayList`. If you want `ArrayList` implementation, use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b"}));
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert an array to a list use [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

```
String[] a = {"Test1", "test2"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(a);
```

To convert an array to a set:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Arrays class ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)):

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

It would depend on your definition of "quickest", but in both cases this would be it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = Arrays.asList(array);

Collections.addAll(list, array);
```

One of the first google link : 
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/converting-array-to-arraylist-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's Guava APIs, using collections is so much simpler.

```
String[] a = {"Test1", "test2"};
List<String> l = Lists.newArrayList(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList() works for your example of String[], but if your're converting a primitive array, such as int[] or double[], then this will produce a single item list of the array.  A good solution is to use Google Guava's primitive helper classes, such as [Ints](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html):

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3}; 
List<Integer> l = Ints.asList(a);
```

For a more detailed explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4324662/317110).