# Why can you cast int[] to Object, but not to Object[]?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, primitive

So this works:

```
int i;
Object a  = (Object) i;
int[] t;
Object b = (Object) t;
String[] s;
Object[] t = (Object[]) s;
```

But this does not:

```
int[] t;
Object[] z = (Object[]) t;
```

All in all I get the first part (boxing), but I find it highly unintuitive that the second part does not work. Is there a specific reason why (beside String inheriting from Object and int not inheriting from Object)?

Edit:

To refine my question, this also works:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = 4;
int d = 2;
Object[] o = new Object[] {a,b,c,d};
```

But then the following does not:

```
int[] t = (int[]) o;
```

Surprisingly you get the same problem with String:

```
String sa = "a";
String sb = "b";
String sc = "c";
String sd = "d";
Object[] so = new Object[] {sa,sb,sc,sd};
String[] st = (String[]) so;
```

Yields a class cast exception on the last line. Still this works:

```
Object[] sy = (Object[])new String[]{sa,sb,sc,sd};
String[] sz = (String[]) sy;
```

Comment: `int` doesn't inherit from anybody.

Comment: Arrays are objects; an array of ints is an array, and thus an object. ints are not objects, so an array of ints is not an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer I was looking for myself. The reason why you cannot cast `int[]` to `Object[]` is not because int is a primitive and does not extend `Object`, but because `int[]` itself does not extend `Object[]`. In code:

```
int[] t = new int[0];
Object ot = t;
System.out.println(ot instanceof Object[]);
// --> prints 'false'
String[] s = new String[0];
Object os = s;
System.out.println(os instanceof Object[]);
// --> prints 'true'
```

Edit: the boxing is necessary because Eclipse knows that `int[]` and `Object[]` are incompatible.

Edit II: Btw this `if(obj instanceof Object[])` allows to check wether a boxed array is an array of a primitive type.

Comment: Re: Edit II: you'd need to make sure that obj is an array as well before that statement is true!
But by any means I'd suggest the following way for curiosity to future readers of your code (including you): `obj.getClass().isArray() && obj.getClass().getComponentType().isPrimitive()`. If you need to "hack", hack well :)

Answer (score 5):

A `int[]` is an array of *primitives* but also an Object itself. It is not an array of Objects

There is no auto-boxing support for arrays.  You need to pick the right type of array to start with and not be converting it at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Any array, including `int[]` is actually an `Object`. This is why you can cast to Object. However, `int` is a primitive, so it doesn't extend `Object`, so you cannot cast to `Object[]`.

Answer (score 1):

As you say: String inheriting from Object and int not inheriting from Object, that's the reason. int, boolean, double... are primitive types and they don't extend from Object. You should use Integer instead of int.

```
Integer[] t;
Object[] z = (Object[]) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

> An object is a class instance or an array.

It is stated in The JLS [section 4.3.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3.1).

Now, `int[]` is an array, which is an Object.

```
String[] s;
```

and

```
int[]
```

differ in following way:

Former can point to an array of `String` objects, but latter can point to an array of primitive `int`.

Comment: Correct link is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

According to Java Spec 4.10.3 [Subtyping among Array Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3):

> - If S and T are both reference types, then S[] ><sub>1</sub> T[] iff S ><sub>1</sub> T.
> - Object ><sub>1</sub> Object[]
> - If P is a primitive type, then Object ><sub>1</sub> P[]

S ><sub>1</sub> T means that T is a direct subtype of S

It basically means, that int[] and Integer[] are in different branches of type hierarchy in Java and can't be cast one to another.